# In @SpringBootTest, is there a way to have SpringRunner.class and Theories.class co-exist?

Tags: spring-boot-test, springrunner

This is hopefully a simple question.

I have a Spring Boot Test.

The annotations are:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations { "myproperties.properties" })
```

I've got a test that I'd love to use @RunWith(Theories.class).  The test is testing basically the same thing over several different places in my code.

Of course, @RunWith must be singular.

So is there a way to have the theories started up as a rule?  Or SpringRunner.class?  Or something so that they can co-exist?

Answer (score 1):

There should be two ways to solve that:

1. **SpringClassRule and SpringMethodRule** *<-- I use this approach*

   just use

   ```
   @RunWith(Theories.class)
   public class YourTest {
       @ClassRule
       public static final SpringClassRule scr = new SpringClassRule();

       @Rule
       public final SpringMethodRule smr = new SpringMethodRule()
   ```
2. **Initializing the TestContextManager Manually** according to [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/springjunit4classrunner-parameterized) it works for **Parameterized**, but I wouldn't know why it shouldn't work for **Theories** also ;)
   *Generally, it is not recommended to initialize the TestContextManager manually. Instead, Spring recommends using SpringClassRule and SpringMethodRule.*

   ```
   @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
   public class YourTest {

       private TestContextManager testContextManager;
       @Before
       public void setup() throws Exception {
           this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
           this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
       }
   ```